# Screen recording tool for the samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, galaxy, galaxy-tab

IS there an available video screen recording tool for the samsung galaxy tab, or any other android device, Thanks

Comment: this belongs to [android enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool named [ashot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/), but the device has to be connected to a PC and it has a pretty low framerate. more instructions [here](http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/09/installing-android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast-for-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no app, or tool that can do this.
The Galaxy tab does have HDMI out via a dongle I believe.
You could get a tv card with HDMI in and hook the tab to the tv card and record it that way.